# ¿Cómo hacer responsivas las columnas de una Data-Tables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Aquí aquí esta mi código para generar la tabla con los respectivos datos que recibe la función ajax, la data que trae los pinto directamente en el succes,el error no es de código, mas bien es un problema de diseño probablemente.

```
function CrearDataTable(cedis, opc) {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'admin/adm_pro/getNeumaticosRemplazar.11.php',
        data:{'opc':opc, 'cedis':cedis},
        type:'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            try{
                window.dataTable.clear();
                window.dataTable.destroy();
            }catch(e){

            }
            // console.log(data);
            var body="";
                for(x in data){
                    var myDate = new Date();
                    var thisMonth = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), 1);
                    //var fecha22=formatDate(thisMonth);
                    // console.log(fecha2);
                    // console.log(formatDate(thisMonth));
                    var mes             = data[x].f_modifica.substr(4,2);
                    var dia             = data[x].f_modifica.substr(6,2);
                    var anio            = data[x].f_modifica.substr(0,4);
                    var fecha           = dia + '-' + mes +'-' + anio ;

                    /* let now = new Date();
                    var fecha1 = moment(fecha);
                    var fecha2 = moment(now.getFullYear() + '-' +  ( now.getMonth() + 1 )  + '-' + now.getDate());
                    console.log(fecha1, fecha2);

                    console.log(fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days'), ' dias de diferencia'); */
                    body = "<tr>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].no_neumatico + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].unidad + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].km + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].marca_unidad + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].tipo + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].placas + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;' class='datatable-fixed'>" + data[x].no_neumatico + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].ubicacion + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].neumatico + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].marca_neumatico + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].medida + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].diseño + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].dr1==1) ? "SI": (data[x].dr1==2) ? "No": "No Revisada") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].dr2==1) ? "SI": (data[x].dr2==2) ? "No": "No Revisada") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].dr3==1) ? "SI": (data[x].dr3==2) ? "No": "No Revisada") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].dr4==1) ? "SI": (data[x].dr4==2) ? "No": "No Revisada") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].presion + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].dot==1) ?        '<i class="iconfa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data[x].dot==0) ? '<i class="icon-remove"></i>' : "Undefined") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].condicion1==1) ? '<i class="iconfa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data[x].condicion1==0) ? '<i class="icon-remove"></i>' : "Undefined") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].condicion2==1) ? '<i class="iconfa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data[x].condicion2==0) ? '<i class="icon-remove"></i>' : "Undefined") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].condicion3==1) ? '<i class="iconfa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data[x].condicion3==0) ? '<i class="icon-remove"></i>' : "Undefined") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].condicion4==1) ? '<i class="iconfa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data[x].condicion4==0) ? '<i class="icon-remove"></i>' : "Undefined") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + ((data[x].condicion5==1) ? '<i class="iconfa-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>' : (data[x].condicion5==0) ? '<i class="icon-remove"></i>' : "Undefined") + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + fecha + "</td>";
                    body += "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + data[x].dias_transcurridos + "</td>";
                    body += "</tr>";
                    jQuery("#dyntable2").append(body);
                }
                window.dataTable = jQuery('#dyntable2').DataTable(
                    {                
                        scrollY:        "auto",
                        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
                        aaSortingFixed: [[0,'asc']],                
                        fnDrawCallback : function(oSettings) {

                            try{
                                jQuery.uniform.update();
                            }catch(e){}
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        fixedHeader: {
                            header: true,
                            footer: false,
                        },
                        scrollX:        true,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        paging:         true,
                        fixedColumns:   {
                            leftColumns: 7,

                        }
                    } 
                );
        }
    })
}
```

Más abajo esta es la estructura de mi tabla en donde inserto la data con jQuery.

El detalle  es que cuando los inserto, el thead no sigue el responsivo de dataTables_length, y quería ver si hay alguna manera de corregir este detalle de la vista.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="dyntable2" name="mitabla" style="width:100%;">
               <colgroup>
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 3%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"   />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"   />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"   />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 3%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 3%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 3%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 3%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 3%"    />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 10%"   />
                  <col class="con0" style="align: center; width: 4%"    />
               </colgroup>
               <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 nosort center">No. Vehiculo</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Unidad</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">KM</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Marca</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Tipo</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Placas</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">No. Neumatico</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Posici&oacute;n</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Neumatico</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Marca</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Medida</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Diseño</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">D.R.1</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">D.R.2</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">D.R.3</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">D.R.4</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Presión</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">DOT</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Condición 1</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Condición 2</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Condición 3</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Condición 4</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Condición 5</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Fecha Inspeccion</th>
                        <th style="background: #A97220;  color: #fff; font-size:10px;"class="head0 center">Días Transcurridos</th>
                     </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody id="mitabalaa"></tbody>
            </table>
```

Aquí dejo un dos imágenes de una cuando la vista está normal y la otra cuando el tamaño de thead no corresponde a la cabecera del datatables_lenght

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Bueno esta es la imagen que muestra la tabla donde aparentemente se ve bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esta segunda imagen es donde el título de las columnas no responden al tamaño responsivo de la tabla. Me gustaría ver si me podrían ayudar con esto.

Comment: Para poder que te funcione la propiedad responsive de DataTables es necesarios que también importes el JS que sugieren en la documentación ¿Validaste esto?

Comment: Si te refieres a esto https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js 
Sí, si lo tengo en mi documento.

Comment: Las tablas no pueden ser responsivas pero sí pueden ser responsivas con respecto a su ancho con un overflow

Comment: Tendrías alguna referencia, o ejemplo? Gracias por contestar!